# @OneToMany Bidirecional

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jpa

Boa tarde, pessoal
estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web financeira e estou com problemas em fazer o relacionamento entre `Lancamento` e `ItemLancamento`. Vou postar o que fiz até agora, esta dando erro ao adicionar item.

CLASSE Lacamento:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANCAMENTO")
public class Lancamento extends GenericModel {

@Column(name = "DESCRICAO", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String descricao;

@Column(name = "DATA_LANCADA", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataCriacao;

@Column(name = "VALOR_LANCADO", nullable = false, precision = 7, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal valorLancamento;

@Column(name = "FIXO", nullable = false)
private Boolean fixo;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CATEGORIA", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "LANCA_CATEGORIA_FK"), nullable = false)
private Categoria categoria;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CONTA", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "LANCA_CONTA_FK"), nullable = false)
private Conta conta;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_USUARIO", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "LANCA_USER_FK"))
private Usuario usuario;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lancamento", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ItemLancamento> itens;
   public void adicionaItensL(ItemLancamento item){
    this.itens.add(item);
    }
```

CLASSE ItemLancamento:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_LANCAMENTO")
public class ItemLancamento extends GenericModel {

@Column(name = "DATA", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date data;

@Column(name = "VALOR", nullable = false, precision = 7, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal valor;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LANCA", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ITEM_LANCA_FK"))
private Lancamento lancamento;
```

CLASSE main()

```
        @Test
        public void salvar() throws ParseException {
        try {

        CategoriaDAO categoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO();
        Categoria categoria = categoriaDAO.buscarPorId(19L);


        ContaDAO contaDAO = new ContaDAO();
        Conta conta = contaDAO.buscarPorId(7L);


        UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDAO.buscarPorId(15L);


        ItemLancamento item = new ItemLancamento();
        item.setData(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/04/2017"));
        item.setValor(new BigDecimal("22.15"));

        if (categoria == null && conta == null || usuario == null && item == null){
            System.out.println("ASSOCIAÇÕES DE LANÇAMENTO NULA!!");
        } else {
            Lancamento lancamento = new Lancamento();
            LancamentoDAO lancamentoDAO = new LancamentoDAO();

            lancamento.setDescricao("Testando meu primeiro lançamento");
            lancamento.setFixo(true);
            lancamento.setDataCriacao(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("14/04/2017"));
            lancamento.setValorLancamento(new BigDecimal("77.56"));


            lancamento.setConta(conta);
            lancamento.setUsuario(usuario);
            lancamento.setCategoria(categoria);

            [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]//PROBLEMA É AQUI.. ACHO
            lancamento.adicionaItensL(item);

            System.out.println("AQUI SALVA 9");

            item.setLancamento(lancamento);
            System.out.println("Lançamento salvo com sucesso!!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: A linha de inserir imagem, não esta no código, coloquei aqui por engano.

Comment: Qual erro? adiciona o log

Comment: ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.edu.unilasalle.model.Lancamento.adicionaItensL(Lancamento.java:64)
 at br.edu.unilasalle.TesteUnitario.LancamentoDAOTest.salvar(LancamentoDAOTest.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

Comment: at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

Comment: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

Comment: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: Desculpa, mas tive que por o erro em algumas partes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lista `itens` não foi instanciada, i.e., você esta tentando adicionar um objeto na lista de itens usando o método `adicionaItens()`, sendo que,  em nenhum momento você instancia a lista de itens.

Comment: Claro.... eu esqueci deste detalhe e é a segunda vez que faço isso... erro de iniciante...kkkkk ... :)

Comment: Franck, pode me ajudar em um outro post que fiz? É sobre herança. Obrigado!